# convert old C++ Winrt dll project based on sample to Windows Run-time Component project

Tags: c++-winrt

I have old C++ Winrt dll project created from C++ WInrt Sample, before project templates were available.

How do i update it to Winrt Runtime Component Project Template, without starting from new project.

I have checked project settings cant find anything conclusive that make both projects differ, but The new style projects work better with Runtime components, specifically you dont get error saying versions of Winrt are different when you try to access Idl generated header files.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

As documented at [Introduction to C++/WinRT: Visual Studio support for C++/WinRT, and the VSIX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/intro-to-using-cpp-with-winrt#visual-studio-support-for-cwinrt-and-the-vsix):

> Alternatively, you can convert an existing project by adding the `<CppWinRTEnabled>true</CppWinRTEnabled>` property to its `.vcxproj` file.
>
> ```xml
> <Project ...>
>     <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
>         <CppWinRTEnabled>true</CppWinRTEnabled>
> ...
> ```
>
> Once you've added that property, you'll get C++/WinRT MSBuild support for the project, including invoking the `cppwinrt.exe` tool.

Comment: Hi thanks once again, adding that line starts the new winrt tool chain, i can see it now generates files when you add winmd from another project. But  Soon as you reference a winmd intellisense dies,  and if you refer anything in the winmd code no build. This works in new project template, and also there is more to do when referencing  winmd in C++ project than just adding the reference, in C# project thats true, not in C++ project. But i now have working method for that, however that is only using new winrt project template, my old project fails on referencing run time component. Cheers

Comment: Error message i get on trying to build code refrencing types in Winmd  "error C2039: 'check_version': is not a member of 'winrt'"  Points to this line of code  static_assert(winrt::check_version(CPPWINRT_VERSION, "1.0.180227.3"), "Mismatched component and base headers."); Thanks

Comment: @iko: Using the C++/WinRT VSIX extension requires Windows SDK version 10.0.17134.0. It looks like you are using an older Windows SDK version. Use the [/showIncludes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/showincludes-list-include-files) compiler option to find out, what's going on. But this is really a different question. The question asked how to enable C++/WinRT tool support in a project generated without using a C++/WinRT project template, and this answer provides a solution to that question.